# Server agent not opening in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I installed  serverAgent 2.2.3
When I run it in cmd I get this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY7cX.png)

I tried starting the startAgent. bat. It automatically closes.
Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

That's very weird because the error states that [sl4j library](https://www.slf4j.org/) cannot be found in [CLASSPATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath) and ServerAgent doesn't use this library at all.

Try [downloading](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent#download) it from Github and unpacking it somewhere else. Also if you have CLASSPATH [environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html) set - try clearing/unsetting it.

```
set CLASSPATH= && startAgent.bat
```

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Alternatively you can try downloading sl4j.jar and dropping it near ServerAgent.jar but it is not a part of normal ServerAgent installation procedure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I got this error when I downloaded SL4J.jar , ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException